# For loop not executing properly, not appending to list

Tags: python

I am trying to create a discord bot for a personal project to better myself at Python programming. However, I ran into an issue. When the bot gets this block of code:

```
def bloodbath(tribs):
    event = "null"
    for person in tribs:
        bloodbath_type = ["bloodbath_solo","bloodbath_duo"]
        output = ["Bloodbath Day."]
        type = random.choice(bloodbath_type)
        if type == "bloodbath_solo":
            output.append((random.choice(bloodbath_solo)) % (person))
        else:
            if len(current_duo) < 2:
                current_duo.append(person)
                if len(current_duo) == 2:
                    output.append((random.choice(bloodbath_duo)) % (current_duo[0], current_duo[1]))
                    current_duo.clear()
        return output

await self.bot.say(bloodbath(tributes))
```

A few issues arise. 
First: The `for person in tribs` loop only runs once, or not at all. Here is an example of an output.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8Nba.jpg

What I want to occur is for the loop to append to the output list 6 times or less (depending if there are situations that call for 2 people) and return it to the bot, where it can input it into the chat.

Here is a hastebin to the entire code.

https://hastebin.com/lumekazula.py

Comment: The value of `tributes` is defined elsewhere. We do not know what is its datatype and size. Show us either an example of the value or the code that produces it.

Comment: Hello Devin, you might want to know about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for next time. Dumping the entire program is usually frowned upon.

Answer (score 0):

The line `return output` breaks the loop and returns immediately. To better understand this problem, try this:

```
def spam():
    for item in [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11]:
        return item * 2

print(spam())  # -> 2
```

Move `output = []` and `return output` to the outside of the loop. You should be able to figure out the rest.